# warning: forward declaration of ‘struct GLUquadric’

Tags: linux, opengl, gcc-warning

I get the following

```
x.cpp: In member function ‘X’:
x.cpp:153:10: warning: possible problem detected in invocation of delete operator:
x.cpp:146:19: warning: ‘quadric’ has incomplete type /usr/include/GL/glu.h:271:7: warning: forward declaration of ‘struct GLUquadric’
x.cpp:153:10: note: neither the destructor nor the class-specific operator delete will be called, even if they are declared when the class is defined.
```

With this code

```
146: GLUquadricObj * quadric;
147: quadric = gluNewQuadric();
148: gluQuadricNormals(quadric, GLU_SMOOTH);
149: gluQuadricTexture(quadric, GL_TRUE);
150:
151: gluSphere(quadric, object.radius(), slices, stacks);
152:
153: delete quadric;
```

I understand why it does that, GLUquadricObj is in fact a foward declaration, BUT

I want to avoid this warning.

I would like either to suppress this warning for that sole function.

Or resolve the warning by including the right header. I used grep in /usr/include/GL and didn't find the complete type.

I'm using Arch Linux

mesa 7.8.2-3

and

gcc 4.5.1-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GLUquadricObj` needs to be deleted using:

```
gluDeleteQuadric(GLUquadricObj *);
```

Answer (score 1):

You mustn't use `delete` for objects not allocated with `new`. Without knowing anything about OpenGL, I'm quite sure you have to use `gluDeleteQuadric` here.